# Java: Fastest way to replace multiple string placeholder

Tags: java, string

What is the fastest way in java to replace multiple placeholders.

For example:
I have a String with multiple placeholder, each has string placeholder name.

```
String testString = "Hello {USERNAME}! Welcome to the {WEBSITE_NAME}!";
```

And a Map which contains the map of what value will be placed in which placeholder.

```
Map<String, String> replacementStrings = Map.of(
                "USERNAME", "My name",
                "WEBSITE_NAME", "My website name"
        );
```

What is the fastest way in java to replace all the placeholder from Map. Is it possible to update all placeholders in one go?

(Please note, I cannot change the placeholder format to {1}, {2} etc)

Comment: the question looks similar. The difference is I wanted to know if I can do that in one go( not replacing the String as many time as my Map keyset)
I can possibly do that by some similar code(for loop and logic), but would love to find out if there is already something in Java which does this.

Comment: If there is a nice one-liner it would be a valid answer to that question, so I doubt there is one. There might be some library that does this, but in the end there will be a loop looping the map/string either way.

Comment: I see :( 
In that case I will close the question.

Comment: Tokenize the text and replace by iterating the tokens once from left to right. The answers suggesting `replace` or `replaceAll` will all need a full pass each and your performance might then degrade. This will become a factor when your map contains maybe 1000 or more entries.

Comment: @Zabuza this is exactly my concern! For my case, each key will appear exactly once, so I don't need a full pass.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`StrSubstitutor`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrSubstitutor.html) class from [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) library:

```
String testString = "Hello {USERNAME}! Welcome to the {WEBSITE_NAME}!";
Map<String, String> replacementStrings = Map.of(
                "USERNAME", "My name",
                "WEBSITE_NAME", "My website name"
        );
StrSubstitutor sub = new StrSubstitutor(replacementStrings , "{", "}");
String result = sub.replace(testString );
```

---

### UPDATE 2024

Since Apache Commons Lang version 3.6 [`StrSubstitutor`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.14.0/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrSubstitutor.html) is *deprecated* and replaced with the [`StringSubstitutor`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.commons/commons-text/1.11.0/org/apache/commons/text/StringSubstitutor.html) class from another library - [Apache Commons Text](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/).

Comment: Work very well. Thank you! May be edit to 'StringSubstitutor', since StrSubstitutor got deprecated? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method to do so:

```
public static String replacePlaceholderInString(String text, Map<String, String> map){
    Pattern contextPattern = Pattern.compile("\\{[\\w\\.]+\\}");
    Matcher m = contextPattern .matcher(text);
    while(m.find()){
        String currentGroup = m.group();
        String currentPattern = currentGroup.replaceAll("^\\{", "").replaceAll("\\}$", "").trim();
        String mapValue = map.get(currentPattern);
        if (mapValue != null){
            text = text.replace(currentGroup, mapValue);
        }
    }
    return text;
}
```

Comment: The inner `replaceAll` should rather be `currentGroup.substring(1, currentGroup.length() - 1)`.

Comment: What if the replacement map contains an entry that maps `a` to `{a} {a} {a}`?

Comment: replacing curly braces with empty string or using substring are same thing. performance wise i think substring will perform better. we should use substring. thanks

Comment: if map contains a to {a} {a} {a} then, this method replace only key, not the values in map everytime, otherwise it will create an infinite loop.